# Dump All XPaths

Tags: python, xml, xpath

Does lxml or exml have a function to export all xpaths in an XML?

XML Example:

```
 <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>
         <content>Don't forget me this weekend!</content>
    </body>
    </note>
```

XPath Results:

```
\\note
\\note\to
\\note\from
\\note\heading
\\note\body
\\note\body\content
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the tree and call [getpath](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#getpath) on each node:

```
x = """<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>
         <content>Don't forget me this weekend!</content>
    </body>
    </note>"""

from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(x))

paths = "\n".join(tree.getpath(n) for n in tree.iter())
print(paths)
```

Output:

```
/note
/note/to
/note/from
/note/heading
/note/body
/note/body/content
```